# How do we cache and restore cookies in Cypress with cy.session?

Tags: cypress

While there is plenty of documentation for persisting cookies across tests using `Cypress.Cookies.defaults(options)`, I can not find a shred of documentation on how to replicate that **and only that** using `cy.session()`;
There are examples on how to use `cy.session()` for login- but all I care about is specifically is cookies.

**The scenario**

I have a spec that contains multiple tests. On the first test, I'm logging in with query parameters that in turn creates a cookie.

I want access to that cookie in subsequent tests. Shouldn't be so hard, right?

In Cypress v10, I have a block of code like this

```
Cypress.Cookies.defaults({
  preserve: 'customAttribution'
});
```

Since that is now longer valid with Cypress 13x, I need to refactor

Related question (but not answered)
[Use cy.session across multiple tests in Cypress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75132971/use-cy-session-across-multiple-tests-in-cypress)

Note: I've included a link to a question that was asked similar to this. The answer given **does not answer either question**

> In Cypress [docs](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/session) cy.session() Cache and restore cookies,
> localStorage, and sessionStorage (i.e. session data) in order to
> recreate a consistent browser context between tests.

This question specifically is asking "how do we do that". It is not a question about how to work around it or an alternative.

Comment: Depending on how your cookie is set, you might use the pattern shown here [How to implement Cypress v10 session() to persist cookies...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74133882/16695029). TLDR - cookies are restored from `Cypress.env()` inside a `beforeEach()`.